Is it possible to save FCM notifications in Firestore?
Send FCM notification to Android device from (Messaging tab) Firebase console. is it possible to save the notification messages in Cloud Firestore ( i.e Firestore database).

Given that we're talking about software and APIs, it's likely possible. Did you try anything yet?

No I have not try, (I am sending notification from Firebase Messaging tab and it should save in Firestore database)

What I have done to get something like this is writing a separate cloud function I can call which both adds it to a document and also sends out a cloud message. Although it is a bit more logic than just using the web console, it also lets me pull
async function sendNotificationToUser(userRef: admin.firestore.DocumentReference<admin.firestore.DocumentData>, user: UserDoc, title, body, link, icon) {
    const sendInAppNotification = user?.settings?.notification?.inapp ?? true
    const sendFcmNotification = user?.settings?.notification?.push ?? true

    if (!user.notifications) {
      user.notifications = []
    }
    const dbNotification: SysNotification = {
      msg: title,
      body,
      link,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      cat: 'GAME_EVENT',
      icon,
    }

    if (sendInAppNotification !== false) {
      user.notifications.push(dbNotification)
      await ref.update({
          notifications: FieldValue.arrayUnion(dbNotification)
      })
    }
    
    if (user.fcm && user.fcm.length && sendFcmNotification !== false) {
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.fcm, {
        notification: {
          title,
          tag: 'GAME_EVENT',
          icon,
          body,
        }
      })
    }
  })
}


There is no built-in export of messages sent from the Firebase console (or through the FCM API) to Firestore.
The closest I can think of is to use the message delivery reports or the BigQuery data export, which do include information about notification sent through the console. You'd have to write code to dig up the information you want, and store it in Firestore through its API.

What I've done for a project is to use a Cloud Function as an intermediary for sending notifications which then can copy the message details and send it to Firestore. This does mean you can't go directly through the web console but it's fairly simple to set up.

Yup, that'd work too - but means you can't use the targeting and scheduling features that the web console offers. It's a valid trade-off though, so I love it if you could post it as an alternative answer so that I can  it.

Okay I've cleaned up and shared my answer

Thanks @NickFelker! Upvoted (which would also be appreciated for my answer of course :-D
